# Custom inspector for HashSet in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, hashset

I am creating an RPG game in Unity. Recently, I have managed to implement custom inspector for HashSet. However, there are two main issues I need help with.

1) **Changes made to Hashset on a prefab/object with Itemslot.cs work but will only last till I quit Unity. In addition, when I make change to prefab and the drag it to scene, newly created object has its HashSet without any changes I made previously to prefab.**

2) **Since Implemented this, editor sometimes freezes indefinetely when I make changes to .cs files and it tries to compile.**

How it looks:

[image]

Itemslot.cs

```
public class Itemslot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
[System.Serializable]
public class HashSetItemType : HashSet<GlobalEnums.ItemType> { }
public HashSetItemType typeAllowed = new HashSetItemType();

[System.Serializable]
public class HashSetClassType : HashSet<GlobalEnums.GameClasses> { }
public HashSetClassType classAllowed = new HashSetClassType();

public int inventoryIndex;
public GameObject socket;

}
```

ItemslotEditor.cs

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Itemslot))]
public class ItemslotEditor : Editor
{


public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{        
    serializedObject.Update();
    Itemslot component = (Itemslot)target;

    GUILayout.BeginVertical("box");

    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("socket"));
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("inventoryIndex"));

    var style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
    int counter = 0;


    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Allowed Types");

    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    foreach (GlobalEnums.ItemType t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(GlobalEnums.ItemType)))
    {
        if (counter % 3 == 0 && counter > 1)
        {
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        }

        if (component.typeAllowed.Contains(t))
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.green;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.white;
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button(t.ToString(), style, GUILayout.Width(120), GUILayout.Height(30)))
        {
            if (component.typeAllowed.Contains(t))
            {
                component.typeAllowed.Remove(t);
            }
            else
            {
                component.typeAllowed.Add(t);
            }
        }

        counter++;

    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
    if (GUILayout.Button("NONE", style, GUILayout.Width(150), GUILayout.Height(25)))
    {
        component.typeAllowed.Clear();
    }

    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.yellow;
    if (GUILayout.Button("ALL", style, GUILayout.Width(150), GUILayout.Height(25)))
    {
        foreach (GlobalEnums.ItemType t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(GlobalEnums.ItemType)))
        {
            component.typeAllowed.Add(t);
        }
    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Allowed Classes");
    counter = 0;

    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    foreach (GlobalEnums.GameClasses t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(GlobalEnums.GameClasses)))
    {
        if (counter % 3 == 0 && counter > 1)
        {
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        }

        if (component.classAllowed.Contains(t))
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.green;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.white;
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button(t.ToString(), style, GUILayout.Width(120), GUILayout.Height(30)))
        {
            if (component.classAllowed.Contains(t))
            {
                component.classAllowed.Remove(t);
            }
            else
            {
                component.classAllowed.Add(t);
            }
        }

        counter++;

    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
    if (GUILayout.Button("NONE", style, GUILayout.Width(150), GUILayout.Height(25)))
    {
        component.classAllowed.Clear();
    }

    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.yellow;
    if (GUILayout.Button("ALL", style, GUILayout.Width(150), GUILayout.Height(25)))
    {
        foreach (GlobalEnums.GameClasses t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(GlobalEnums.GameClasses)))
        {
            component.classAllowed.Add(t);
        }
    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.EndVertical();

    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity cannot serialize `HashSet<T>`, so your changes will never be saved to disk.

You have two options here:

- Use `List<T>`. This type can be serialized by Unity, as long as `T` can be serialized too.
- Implement [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) to handle the serialization yourself, e.g. store the HashSet's contents in a List when serializing and move them back into the HashSet when deserializing. See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-Custom.html

**edit**

Here is an example how you could do it using the `ISerializationCallbackReceiver` interface.

```cs
public class Itemslot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, 
IPointerExitHandler, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public HashSet<GlobalEnums.ItemType> typeAllowed = new HashSet<GlobalEnums.ItemType>();

    // private field to ensure serialization
    [SerializeField]
    private List<GlobalEnums.ItemType> _typeAllowedList = new List<GlobalEnums.ItemType>();

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        // store HashSet contents in List
        _typeAllowedList.Clear();
        foreach(var allowedType in typeAllowed)
        {
            _typeAllowedList.Add(allowedType);
        }
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        // load contents from the List into the HashSet
        typeAllowed.Clear();
        foreach(var allowedType in _typeAllowedList)
        {
            typeAllowed.Add(allowedType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) I belive it serializes. It is well known hack that if you do `public class HashSetItemType : HashSet<GlobalEnums.ItemType> { }` then Unity can serialize. http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/462070/view.html

Comment: 2) ISerializationCallbackReceiver si know to cause werid problems probably connected to multi threading. See this [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/serializeable-dictionary-exceptions-after-code-change.319285/#post-2167881) and this [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/iserializationcallbackreceiver-throwing-exceptions.329917/#post-2167896)

Comment: I would not trust the hack to work, especially since the post you linked is 4 years old.

Yes, Serialization is done in another thread but this is just a thing you'll have to work with. As stated in your second link, it is possible to avoid those problems.

Comment: Ok. My experience with C# and editor internal behavior is limited, so can you provide an example how to use it? Do I need to do special class for every type of hashset?

Comment: And in custom inspector I need to fill the List if I understand correctly?

Comment: No you can just continue to use the HashSet. The List is solely used to serialize the HashSet.

Comment: Nonetheless you should call `EditorUtility.SetDirty(component)` just before `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()`

Comment: It works! I just needed to modify the beginning to `public HashSet<GlobalEnums.ItemType> typeAllowed = new HashSet<GlobalEnums.ItemType>();` since I was getting errors. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `EditorUtility.SetDirty(target)` whenever something changes. Otherwise Unity won't detect that the values inside your collections are changing so it won't save them.

Comment: Not experienced with editor scripts, so in this case, what should be target? `component`?

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. Also tried marking the scene dirty but neither the prefab or objects in scene seem to remember when I restart Unity.